# Qt C++ QStyledItemDelegate subclass - Mouse over paint

Tags: c++, qt, qstyleditemdelegate

I have sub-classed `QStyledItemDelegate` (just the paint function) and applied to my `QTableview` along with my custom `QAbstractTableModel` model for the data.
The cells of the Table are drawn correctly, so are when selected, but the color for the Mouse Over is not. What do i miss ?
Here is the paint function.. Cells are all black, the selected goes green, but when mouse is over any cell, i dont get the red color.

```
void  Mydelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
         painter->save();

            if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) {
                painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(Qt::red));
            } else if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
                painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(Qt::green));
             } else painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(Qt::black));

            painter->restore();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry figured it out. Forgot to add mouse tracking in my viewport

```
ui->table->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Sorry for that, please mark as Solved (or even delete my post if not useful)

Comment: This came useful as I ran into the exact same. You should be able to accept your own answer.